# Not showing edit record in list users on airflow when connecting using LDAP

Tags: ldap, airflow, airflow-2.x

I've installed latest version of Airflow.
When configured to use LDAP, edit record in users list is not showing.
[image]

When configured for auth db it works as expected.

[image]

Is it a bug maybe?

Comment: Same here. We migrate from 1.10.12 to 2.1.2. We are using kubernetes. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem! We were using airflow v1, and migrated to v2, without migrate the helm chart version. We solved migrating the helm chart version.
In our case, we were using the 7.14.0 version and then, according to the [recommendation](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow#airflow-version-support) from the repo where we got the chart, we migrate to 8.5.2 version.

That's because, depending on the chart version you're using, it is not recommended for airflow 2.